# How do I create an automatic field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model that looks like:

```
var CompanySchema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , logoUrl: String
  , created: {
      type: Date,
      default: new Date().toUTCString() 
  }
  , deleted: {
      type: Date,
      default: null 
  }
});
```

I want to have a field called `id` as well (this is on top of the `_id` that already gets added). So how can I create the `id` field and have it automatically assigned to the value of `_id`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
CompanySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  this.id = this._id;
  next();
});
```

Comment: For anyone coming along later, it seems Mongoose now automatically adds a virtual attribute 'id', so this is probably no longer needed (at least as of Mongoose 3.8.x).